# zendframework 3 - service execute twice

Tags: zend-framework3

I have created a personalized service to determine the users' language.
I call my service inside the Module class of my Moduel.php like this:

```
    $languageService = $sm->get("LanguageService");
    $languageService->setLanguage();
```

The configuration of the service is instead found inside the global.php configuration file as well as the code below.

```
'service_manager' => [
        'factories' => [
            \Application\Service\LanguageService::class =>  \Application\Service\Factory\LanguageServiceFactory::class
        ],
        'aliases'=>[
            'LanguageService'=>\Application\Service\LanguageService::class
        ]
    ],
```

The problem using xdebug the code is executed twice (constructor and methods)

I have noticed that the code is actually executed twice. The first time the url of the request is / therefore my index. The second call is the url /css/bootstrap-select.css.map. I think it's an internal call to the plugin. I do not think the behavior is correct.

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour is correct. You have a problem with your server. I do not know the fix for `nginx` type, but for Apache, using `.htaccess` you should add a bit of code that serves files from the public directory straight away instead of going through the application.

By default, the [Zend Skeleton Application](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication) comes with the following `.htaccess` file content in the `public/` directory ([source](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication/blob/master/public/.htaccess)):

```
RewriteEngine On
# The following rule tells Apache that if the requested filename
# exists, simply serve it.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [L]
# The following rewrites all other queries to index.php. The 
# condition ensures that if you are using Apache aliases to do
# mass virtual hosting or installed the project in a subdirectory,
# the base path will be prepended to allow proper resolution of
# the index.php file; it will work in non-aliased environments
# as well, providing a safe, one-size fits all solution.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}/index.php [L]
```

The project root directory does not come with an `.htaccess` file. If you correctly map your server to use the project `public/` directory as the projects access point, you won't need it.

---

Based on comment discussion, I'm assuming somewhere some config is not correct and is directing the `/css/*` requests to the project root. To make sure that those requests do not enter the project I have the following `.htaccess` in my project root:

```
RewriteEngine On

# If URL to the application is http://foo.com/path/to/ZendSkeletonApplication/
# the set the base to /path/to/ZendSkeletonApplication/
RewriteBase /

# Remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Below is ZF2 default
RewriteRule ^\.htaccess$ - [F]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =""
RewriteRule ^.*$ public/index.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^public/.*$ public/index.php [NC,L]
```

Not very pretty, but it gets the job done.

Comment: The root directory of host is public folder and htaccess is the same that You have posted. What I wrong?

Comment: Did you check you're using Apache and not nginx?

Comment: Yes, my web server is Apache

Comment: And you're sure the `httpd-vhosts.conf` file says `DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/project/public"` ? I'll add another `.htaccess` file to my answer, but that's for in the root of the project.

Comment: yes. All css and js cause reload of service. Maybe wamp  server issue? I'm developing on windows system.

Comment: I use Xampp (& thus Apache) locally. Sometimes other setups (like local Docker with Alpine/Php/MySql setups). But the local Xampp/Apache/MySQL works for me. Double requests (for me) are an issue of not catching them server side (Apache). So if they, for you, persist after what I gave in my answer/comments, then you have another issue and for nowI do not know what. Sorry mate ;-) Another time (or more/different info required)

Comment: I debugged in depth and I found that it is a css, js file and images that it does not find. These calls occur within the various frameworks (eg bootstrap). So I think the solution is to edit the htaccess file to handle this type of file and not just those that can solve.

Comment: Actually, no they don't. If files are requested which don't exist the problem is in your generated HTML. If you include for example a `<scrypt src="/here.js"></script>`, the `.htaccess` files I gave you instantly return the file if it exists. If if does not exist, the application will be called with that route. If it then does not exist, you'll get an error. If your css contains a reference to a `*.css.map` file, that file must also exist. If you're using Bootstrap, regenerate the files.

Comment: What you could do, in addition to making sure all files referenced in your output, is to make find a additional `.htaccess` rule which does not allow files to be directly called. Not sure how to write that, but along the lines of: "if request has extension .png|.css|.js|.ico then serve file, if file does not exist, close request"